# How to reduce probability of collision while using RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(20) in java?

Tags: java, unique

I want to generate an alphanumeric unique number of length 20 in java every time when it is called.

There is UUID() but the length exceeds 20. so I tried RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(20) but I know there are chances of a collision.
Is it a good idea to generate two random alphanumerics of length 10 and concatenate them to generate 20 length number.

Comment: Generating two random strings of length 10 and concatenating them will not help. It will give you exactly the same chance of a collision as when you generate a random string of length 20 - because it comes down to doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: With 20 random alphanumeric characters the chance of a collision happening because of random chance is *way lower* than the chance of a collision happening because of a badly chosen or configured random source. For example, using a time-seeded `Random` can lead to collisions much more often than random chance would otherwise suggest.

Comment: Keep in mind `UUID` is actually just two `long` values that can be represented by a string. It's really just a random 128-bit value (and taking each 4 bits to represent a character). In that same vein, you could generate a random 80-bit value with characters represented in a similar fashion, or you could also just use UUID and represent them with something more succinct than 16 characters. For instance, a UUID represented by 255 different characters (8 different bits) allows for a string of length 16.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your UUID is already random, why not just trim it to size 20?

```
"AVeryLongRandomUUIDCodeHere".substring(0, 20);
```

Comment: Will it guarantee uniqueness or a lower collision rate than what I mentioned?

Comment: Depends on how your UUID is created.But in general, if they are already randomly created, it will be cheaper to simply use it than create a new random String.

Comment: Also, I don't think you can get a better uniqueness or collision rate since your dealing with random values already.

Comment: Be careful with the substring as the first 20 character of your UUID generation might be using a specific variable such as time to generate those characters. It might be a better solution to randomly pick 20 characters from your generated UUID. However, neither this solution nor using UUID guarantee that there will never be a collision.